# Allowing Wordpress to be hosted on a subfolder within an already existing site

Tags: wordpress, nginx, docker

We have a request from a client where we need to host a wordpress site within our website. By within, I mean that the site can't sit in a subdomain, i.e https://blog.example.com, instead it needs to sit in its own route/subfolder, i.e. https://www.example.com/blog. This is due to page ranking (apparently page rankings are penalised if they are put in subdomains)

The issue is, our site isn't run in PHP (its written in Scala that runs on Jetty). Furthermore, our main site is run from a Docker container that is backed by Nginx.

Ideally I would want to host Wordpress on its own single server (either Docker containerized or not, its not a huge issue), and in the nginx configuration for our main site, have it reverse to that external server for the specific URL (i.e. https://www.example.com/blog would point to an IP/host of an external server that is running wordpress)

How would you achieve this/is it possible? This is the current `nginx.conf` for our main server

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen       443 default_server ssl;
    server_name  www.example.com.au;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EDH+aRSA+SHA256:EDH+aRSA:EECDH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED";

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
         proxy_redirect http://www.example.com.au /;
         proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
         proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
         proxy_read_timeout 600s;
         port_in_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This is an example of our current `nginx.conf`, as you can see, the actual website is being hosted on `localhost:8080` and we are just proxy redirect for the main site.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the `wordpress` service is hosted in `http://localhost:8081`, then you can just `proxy_pass` the `/blog` requests to `http://localhost:8081`, you can just add following block into your `nginx` `server` block:

```
    location ^~ /blog {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    }
```